# GDB Version error on Eclipse CDT in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gdb, ubuntu-16.04, eclipse-cdt

I installed Eclipse Oxygen CDT on Ubuntu 16.04. I am using the default gdb installed.

When I try to launch the debugger in eclipse, I get the following error:

```
 Error with command: gdb -version
```

I suspected that this could be because eclipse was unable to find the gdb program, so i mentioned the whole path of the gdb program in the "Preferences =>C/C++ => GDB" options.

Still the error persists. Can anybody tell me how I can fix this error? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does `gdb -version` work from your command line?

Comment: yes it works. gdb is installed. I also don't see any  path issues.

Answer (score 0):

check gdb version from c:\MINGW\bin\gdb32.exe "I have this version"
then got Eclips >> Preferences >> C/C++ >> GDB
then in GDB path "First block" click browse then insert the GDB path
Done ^-^